# woocommerce add subtitle on menu navigation on my account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i got in stuck with a customization that i want to do on myaccount navigation menu in the Woocommerce account.

I want to add inside the li tag a subtitle under the menu item name, the item that he get from wc_get_account_menu_items() function, but it doesn't have any subtitle in the $item.

How can i customize it in order to insert it in the navigation.php

I attach a file where it shows how it have to be rendered

I thought to insert an action at wc_get_account_menu_items in order to add teh subtitle but i can't figure out how :(

Thank you

Mirko[image: navigation]

Comment: what is the screenshot about?

Comment: to the woocommerce myaccount

Comment: it's how i want to become. I have already changed the menu items and the order. I have to add that subtitle that appear under the title item in light gray

Comment: you have to create your own `woocommerce/myaccount/navigation.php` for this.

Comment: i have the navigation.php in my child theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the HTML you required (as per screenshot) using `woocommerce_account_menu_items()` filter or any other filter.

So if you need the same structure, it is better to hard code the links & HTML in your theme by copying navigation.php from `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\myaccount` to `wp-content\themes\your-theme\woocommerce\myaccount`.

Comment: i did it. But how can i insert into html inside the foreach loop each text ?

Comment: You don't need that foreach loop. There is no use in your situation. So first prepare the HTML & then instead of the default code use your HTML with PHP.

Comment: But i have a foreach loop that iterate every item in wc_get_account_items and have an html li tag where goes the item name. Under that i have to put a subtitle related to the item that it is

Comment: Where can i have my subtitles. I was thinking to make an array with all subtitles with key name the endpoint and with an if i check if endpoint match and write the subtitle